# Some doubt on $L^\infty$ of measure space

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory

Is it true that $\oplus L^{\infty}(X,\mu_{n})=L^{\infty}(X,\mu)$, where $\mu=\oplus 1/2^n(\mu_{n})$, for any sigma finite class of measures?Then can you please explain how the spectral representations $L^{\infty}(X,\mu_{n})$ of  will give spectral representations of  $L^{\infty}(X,\mu)$. I could not understand the construction of single measure in HAHN-HELLINGER theorem by joining of measures of each cyclic representation, how the direct sum of $\oplus L^{\infty}(X,\mu_{n})$ remembers the spectral multiplicity?

Comment: Can you explain what these notations mean?  I would think that $\mu=\oplus\mu_n$ would mean that $L^\infty(X,\oplus \mu_n)=L^\infty(X,\mu)$ just by substitution, but maybe the notation has some special meaning here...

Comment: Where $\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu_{n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mu =\sum_n \mu_n$ then $L^{\infty } (\mu)$ is the intersection of the spaces $L^{\infty } (\mu_n)$, not their sum.

Comment: Then can you please explain how the spectral representations of $L^\infty(\mu_{n})$  will give spectral representations of $L^\infty(\mu)$